# How to properly save array of objects with mongoose + nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of names:

var names = ["Kelley", "Amy", "Mark"]

Assuming Person is just a Mongoose model for nodejs... I want to save each name as a document into mongodb with the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
           name_now = names[i];
        Person.findOne({ name: name_now},
            function(err, doc) {
                if(!err && !doc) {
                    var personDoc = new PersonDoc();
                    personDoc.name = name_now;
                    console.log(personDoc.name);
                    personDoc.save(function(err) {});
                } else if(!err) {
                    console.log("Person is in the system");
                } else {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + err);
                }
            }
        )   
}
```

I am having issues as I keep geting a "Error creating schedule: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index:..... dup key: {: "Mark"}". And it appears that it is trying to insert "Mark" (the last element in the list) 3 times as opposed to each of the names in the list.

When I try to print out the name of the current person in the loop (with the console.log(personDoc.name);), I get "Mark" 3 times... and it appears that it only saved "Mark" in the database and no one else... what is the proper way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the `findOne` callbacks, `name_now` is always going to be set to the last name in `names` because the `for` loop completes before the first callback is even called.  You need to create an immediate function to capture the current `name_now` value during each iteration and preserve it for use in the callback:

```
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    (function (name_now) {
        Person.findOne({ name: name_now},
            function(err, doc) {
                if(!err && !doc) {
                    var personDoc = new PersonDoc();
                    personDoc.name = name_now;
                    console.log(personDoc.name);
                    personDoc.save(function(err) {});
                } else if(!err) {
                    console.log("Person is in the system");
                } else {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + err);
                }
            }
        );   
    )(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! But I want to after the for loop executes, within the same function to do a Person.find({}) to get all of the documents after insert. How do I make sure the loop finishes before I perform the Person.find({})?

Comment: @Damascusi Best to post that as a separate question as it's non-trivial.  Do some searches first as that's a common case.